# VideoView doesn't take proper width

Tags: java, android

Right now I have this:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"/></LinearLayout>
```

It actually works the problem is the video. It doesn't take full width of the LinearLayout. I have tried with:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

video.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,4f));
```

But didn't work.

I want to have something like this:

```
****text****
------------
************
***video****
************
```

Thanks